# GWT Autobean without setter method

Tags: json, gwt, autobean

I am using Autobean framework to encode/decode JSON in my GWT application. It works in cases with the interfaces having getters and setters. But is there any way to do it some other way to do this without specifying a `setThisCollectionProperty` instead using an `addToThisCollectionProperty` method?

For example, I have an interface `IPerson` like this:

```
public interface IPerson {
       public String getName();
       public void setName(String name);

       public int getAge();
       public void setAge(int age);

       public List<String> getIds();
       public void addId(String id);
}
```

BeanFactory is like this:

```
public interface BeanFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {

    public AutoBean<IPerson> person();

    public AutoBean<IPerson> person(IPerson person);


}
```

and in Person class which implements IPerson,

```
public class Person implements IPerson {
       private String name;
       private List<String> ids;
       ...

       public List<String> getIds() {
              return ids;
       }

       public void addId(String id) {
              ...
              ids.add(id);
       }
}
```

It works if the `addId(String id)` is replaced with `setIds(List<String> ids)`.
Otherwise the following error is shown:

> The com.mycompany.jsonsample.beans.IPerson parameterization is not simple, but the person method does not provide a delegate

Is it possible to encode/decode without a `set` method?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. By convention java uses setters and getters for reflection.

Comment: @ChristianAchilli isn't there any way to do it by specifying the property to be handled with that function?

Comment: Not that I know. Actually I am not sure why you want to do this. Person is supposed to be a DTO from a JSON perspective. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ChristianAchilli I have to encode/decode instances of some library interfaces' implementations. Most of those interfaces have just getters and setters, but some have methods like the `addId` method in my example instead of a collection setter method.

Comment: As far as I know that isn't possible. Your bean needs to follow the naming conventions. (i.e. `getProperty`, `setProperty`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoBean manages all getters and setters, and only getters and setters. For any other method, you have to use a [*category*](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#Categories).

Using a category, you could thus implement `addId(…)` as `getIds().add(…)`, or possibly directly call `addIds` on [the underlying object](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/AutoBean.html#unwrap%28%29) if the `AutoBean` [is a wrapper](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/AutoBean.html#isWrapper%28%29).